# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/auth/kerberos/KeyTab

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new in hadoop. I am trying to run a job by toolrunner of hadoop from java code in netbeans environment. But still I can't find a solution to fix the issue.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/auth/kerberos/KeyTab
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.(UserGroupInformation.java:609)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:799)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.(FileSystem.java:2812)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.(FileSystem.java:2802)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2668)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
>       at org.enahang.mapreduce.utils.mrUtils.Test.run(Test.java:125)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.enahang.mapreduce.utils.mrUtils.Test.main(Test.java:62)

My platform is windows 7.

---

I’ve added many libraries. First of all I’ve added the
`Apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar`
Then I added many other libraries similar
`Javaee-api-7.0.jar`
`java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar`
… 
But I don’t know from where the error arises.

This is the complete list of .jar files I added to include Keytab class in code:
`apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar`
`api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar`
`api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar`
`commons-cli-1.2.jar`
`commons-codec-1.4.jar`
`commons-collections-3.2.1.jar`
`commons-configuration-1.6.jar`
`jsp-api-2.1.jar`
`hadoop-auth-2.7.0.jar`

Thanks in advance

Comment: before getting this error my hadoop core was hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar. But because of an error of read/write permission in win 7, and a hint about using hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar, I removed the first jar and then I added the second jar

Comment: I think, I resolved the problem by adding `hadoop-conf-kerberos-6.0.0.jar`. However, a new error is arised as such: " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think for this question the research is enough; The answer is that `hadoop-conf-kerberos-6.0.0.jar` contains some xml and properties files for configuration of hadoop with respect to kerberos. The problem of my program to find the class of KeyTab was the result of a bad configuration.
`[hadoop-conf-kerberos-6.0.0.jar][1]`contains prepared configuration files similar `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, etc. It complemented the `Apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar` I had added to my program.